# How do I replicate `netstat -b` with Get-NetTCPConnection?

Tags: powershell, netstat

I'm playing with [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps) as a replacement for `netstat`. I need a solution for the `-b` flag, as the cmdlet only shows an `OwningProcess` PID.

> -b Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port.

https://www.computerhope.com/netstat.htm

Answer (score 2):

I would go with:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | select-Object LocalAddress, LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State , OwningProcess  , @{l="Name" ;e= {Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty Name } } | Format-Table
```

For easier usage, it could be wrapped to function:

```
Function MyNetStat {Get-NetTCPConnection | select LocalAddress, LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State , OwningProcess  , @{l="Name" ;e= {Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty Name } } }
```

Which could be added to your `profile.ps1`:

```
'Function MyNetStat {Get-NetTCPConnection | select LocalAddress, LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State , OwningProcess  , @{l="Name" ;e= {Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty Name } } }' | Out-File "$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1" -Append
```

Hope that helps.